so/as does Jim and Tom OR so/as do Jim and Tom
I like it so/as does Jim. This sentence means I like it and Jim also likes it.
I am wondering that if there are two other persons also like it what should I put after so/as.
Which of the followings is right? Or are they both right?
I like it so/as DOES Jim and Tom.
I like it so/as DO Jim and Tom.
Thank you for your kind help.

This question on ELU discusses inversion following so.

Thanks. What about this sentence which is from IELTS Reading. Relaxation lowers metabolic rate, as DOES adequate sleep and in general an equable and balanced personality. Do you have any ideas that why DOES was used here since there are apparently another TWO things can also slow metabolic rate ?

So is not idiomatic here unless it starts a new sentence, or at least follows a distinct break such as a semicolon or a dash.
Jim and Tom are two people, so the plural form of the verb is required.

I like it; so do Jim and Tom.

As only requires a comma, but it sounds rather formal.

I like it, as do Jim and Tom.


Thank you Ms. Bunting. You are always helpful. You answer was my thought until I met this sentence which is from IELTS Reading. The sentence is below. Relaxation lowers metabolic rate, as DOES adequate sleep and in general an equable and balanced personality. Obviously, there are other TWO things can also lower metabolic rate and they are adequate sleep and an equable and balanced personality . Therefore I am so confused that why DOES was used here, which the plural form of the verb should be required. I will post the entire paragraph below in case I misunderstood anything.

It follows from the above that sparing use of energy reserves should tend to extend life. Extreme high performance sports may lead to optimal cardiovascular performance, but they quite certainly do not prolong life. Relaxation lowers metabolic rate, as does adequate sleep and in general an equable and balanced personality. Each of us can develop his or her own ‘energy saving programme’ with a little self-observation, critical self-control and, above all, logical consistency. Experience will show that to live in this way not only increases the life span but is also very healthy.

I suppose the writer regarded in general as starting a new section of the sentence.  Relaxation and sleep are things you can do to lower your metabolic rate, but an equable personality is something you either have or you haven't. Compare: I prefer this one; so does Jim, and Tom told me last week that he doesn't mind either way.

My understanding in general here means in the main, on the whole, by and large, this kind of meanings. An individual may cry a lot or laugh a lot sometimes, which I think is inevitable for most people, but his/her personality is relatively peaceful at the most time, which can be called in general an equable and balanced personality. Hence, adequate sleep and in general an equable and balanced personality both lower metabolic rate. If in general as starting a new section of the sentence it seems to be an incomplete sentence for me as the new section doesn’t make a full sense.

Perhaps 'starting a new section' wasn't the best way to explain what I mean.  Relaxing and getting enough sleep are both things you are more likely to do if you have an equable personality, so in general suggests that having one includes the first two and probably other things as well (such as not being prone to losing your temper).

having one includes the first two and probably other things as well (such as not being prone to losing your temper). one do you mean personality？ first two do you mean relaxation and sleep？

Yes!! I had just mentioned having an equable personality, so having one simply avoids repetition.

I appreciate your kind help but I am not convinced. The relationship between equable and balanced personality and relaxation and, especially adequate sleep, I feel, is a little bit far-fetched. Anyway, thank you.
